# Delete Last Item From Grid View - > Linq & SQL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I have the following table:

**Messages**
ID(PK) int auto_inc
Message varchar(100)

I would like to delete the last added item in the table, i.e. the one with the highest ID?

I have the following so far:

```
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DemoDataDataContext db = new DemoDataDataContext();

            //locate the record with the highest ID
            var deleteQuery =
                (from d in db.Messages
                 select d).Max();

            //remove it from the database

        }
```

I can find the highest ID, but not sure on the syntax whenit comes to deleting that record...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DemoDataDataContext db = new DemoDataDataContext();

            //locate the record with the highest ID
            var deleteQuery =
                (from d in db.Messages
                 order by d.ID
                 select d).LastOrDefault();

            //remove it from the database
            db.Messages.DeleteOnSubmit(deleteQuery);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
```

this uses `LastOrDefault()` and will also delete the last item from the database.

Answer (score 0):

try using LastOrDefault(); instead of max to get last record in your linq statemtn...or in your query do a descend sort on your primary id and select top(1)..

Answer (score 0):

If DemoDataDataContext gives you the [DeleteAllOnSubmit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.itable.deleteallonsubmit.aspx) method (I'm not near intellisense right now), you could use:

```
db.Messages.DeleteOnSubmit(deleteQuery).submitChanges();
```

Comment: Sorry but you shouldn;t answer if you can't back your assumption. Btw, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your context in using. Use 'Remove'. Call SaveChanges.

```
public void DeleteLastMessage()
{
  using (var db = new DemoDataDataContext())
  {
    var lastMessage = (from m in db.Messages
                     orderby m.ID
                     select m)
                .LastOrDefault();

    db.Messages.Remove(lastMessage);
    db.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```